# Vista PC - Continually losing space on my C Drive

Tags: windows-vista, disk-space

I am having a problem with my C Drive as it continually loses free space.  I keep backing up and deleting files, but the easy ones are all off (those folders that are 100 MB and larger that can be easily moved or backupped and deleted from the C).

I did free up the 100 GB drive to 8 GB, but a couple of weeks later it was down to 4 GB.  I searched for new or modified files in that time, but there was no substantial files (bigger than 1 MB).  So I am not sure why I am increasing usage / losing free space.

I used http://windirstat.info/ to find out where my disk space is has gone, but could not see any change either.

I have norton anti-virus, but it hasn't found anything.

I thought maybe it had something to do with the two large .sys files, but with 3 GB of RAM, my friend tells me the sizes of my hiberfil.sys (3.15 GB) and pagefile.sys (3.45 GB) are appropriate.

I have also tried defragmenting.  For some reason, this made it worse.  Recently I removed files to go from 3 GB free space back up to 5 GB.  In that time though, the free space dropped to 4.6 GB.  Then when I ran the defragment tool on Vista, the free space went down to 2 GB!

Any suggestions?

(Side question - the only other thing I can find to delete of considerable size is .cab files in the C:\Windows\SWSetup.  It seems they are tied to programs.  Can I deletes these files, especially if they are all older than 2 years old?)

Comment: Do you have any backup software installed?

Comment: The SuperUser Blog has a few articles regarding missing hard drive space at http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/07/where-did-all-my-hard-drive-space-go/

Comment: yes RonK, thanks.  I have back up software that came with my Western Digital external hard drive - WD Smartware  . . .  The timing of the problem may coincide if that is what you are thinking. . . . Sehe did below correctly identify that Vista's backup restore is running wild (UNBOUNDed).  Might be connected to the WD Smartware software.  I am hoping to hear how much I should limit the size to.

Comment: Thank you Mokubai, I am trying the Advanced SystemCare 4 from page 3 of the link from your link.  Still, I think the main problem is provided below.

Comment: BTW Mokuai, I ran the Advanced System Care 4.  It cleaned up thousands of problems, but did not free up any C Drive space.  So while I am sure it is helpful and a good program to run, it did not address the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: @Mokubai, perhaps you should add a summary of your post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may (as in likely) have system restore points enabled. You can clean those up, and put a maximum on the volume used for restore points

Here is one guid on how to do that: http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-reduce-disk-space-used-by-windows-vista-system-restore.html

Comment: An of course the Disk Cleanup app if you haven't already run it.

Comment: The directions on the link are very helpful.  Since I am using 26 GB of Shadow Copy Storage, 27 GB Allocated and the Maximum is UNBOUNDED, I believe you are correct!  Thank you very much.

The link also provides how to reduce or limit the allocation for this functionality.  It does not say how much I should allocate though.  Can you recommend how I figure this out?

Comment: Yes I did run the Disk Cleanup Spectre. Thanks.

Comment: @sehe, please see the question above on resizing the Shadow Copy Storage Allocation.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on administering Windows systems (I tend to stay away :)) but here goes. I reckon a healthy Vista installation should be 10-12Gb (for the OS + basic tooling). Add some WinSxS (8Gb?) room and some space for shadow copies (say, 12Gb): a toal footprint of 32Gb ought to be enough. But, hey I'm on linux because I think Windows fills up my SSD far too quickly

Comment: @sehe.  Thanks again.  Then again, my problem isn't solved because I didn't have enough space at 27 GB, let alone expanding to 32 GB.  If anyone else has ideas, please feel free.

Comment: @user82585: that's why I warned I'm not the expert. I was trying to err on the safe side, not knowing your situation. If you ask me, I'd run without any System Restore Points. You don't _need_ that: it is just for convenience should you ever need to recover things. You could try setting it to 2Gb instead and see whether Windows would complain when it would otherwise need more storage. AFAICT it will just forget about the 'old' restore points. I'm sorry to have confused you, I was assuming too much.

Comment: @sehe:  I definitely appreciate all of your suggestions, including your best guess.  I am a complete neophyte, so any guidance is good guidance. . . . I reduced the size to 20 GB (from 27+ GB)to see what would happen.  The only noticeable change was that I lost my current files list in Microsoft Office (but not the files themselves).

Comment: @sehe: So I was able to create 20 GB of free space initially, up from 2 GB, but that quickly (within hours) changed to 15 GB.  One day later, I'm down to 13.8 GB with only 30 MB of new files.  So I have enough space for now, but hope the declining free space isn't still happening.  Will let you know.

Comment: I must admit that doesn't seem normal. Could you look at windirstat before and after to identify where the growth is?

Comment: I did look at it once before and will try again.  Is there a specific tool on there that I should use?  My impression was it is like Windows Explorer, except it provides a breakdown by highest usage.  Is there a report creating tool on there I didn't see?

Comment: 'fraid not (I use kdirstat on linux, which is the original program before it came to windows). But you manually can chalk up the 10 biggest directories (don't pick those at the topmost level, or you won't spot the most striking changes)